# MAUI Entry shows Bindet Text only in white TextColor

Tags: maui

When I start my Maui App using iPhone in dark mode and switch to a page with a form, the binding Text in the Entries is always white on (correct) white Background. On other OS or in light mode the TextColor is Black. I have set Black as TextColor at the Style.xaml for all Entry and on the special Entry I set it Black too.

When I change the binding Text to a fixed Text="Test" it appears black. When the text is white I can positioning the cursor behind, so I see there is white Text. When the Text is white and I turn the phone from portrait to landscape, the TextColor changes to black. When I come back to this Page a further time than the TextColor is black. At the constructor, I tried to swap `InitializeComponent();` with `BindingContext = _profileEditViewModel;` but it does not makes any changes.

Why the Text in the Entry is white instead of black?
Any ideas?

```
<Entry Text="{Binding EditConnectionProfile.Server}"  TextColor="Black" />
```

Comment: You mean you are having issues with HotReload or the issue with complete build

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not using the AppThemeBinding which is probably what is causing this issue, what you should do eg for your text is this:

```
<Label Text="Something" TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
```

More information in this MS blog article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes?view=net-maui-8.0

Comment: I want to have the TextColor allways black, at light and at dark mode.

Comment: So just set it to black in both cases bro...

Comment: Also TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource Black}}" shows text in white color.

Comment: Do you have these StaticResources defined in your Colors?

Comment: Yes. <Color x:Key="White">White</Color>
<Color x:Key="Black">Black</Color>

Comment: Also at Styles.xaml:     <Style TargetType="Entry">
        <Setter Property="TextColor"
                Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource Black}}" />

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by moving the assignment of the bound object to a earlier time. To be precise, I created and filled the object before the view with the entry (and the white text on a white background) was created.

There used to be an issue about this, but it was closed. It does not mention (perhaps nobody noticed) that the problem only occurs in dark mode.
[github maui issues](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17843)

Comment: 1. Nice catch, can you help explain clearly on the solution `move the assignment of the bound object to a earlier time`? 2.  You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I have adapted it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few bugs in MAUI related to setting TextColor on Entry in iOS.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17818

[MAUI Entry shows Bindet Text only in white TextColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77861255/maui-entry-shows-bindet-text-only-in-white-textcolor)

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17843

Basically, when on iOS Dark Mode, the Entry TextColor specified value is ignored and, instead, the device will come up with a color that is "close enough" to display nicely depending on the background.

I just can't wait for MAUI to fix it as they take way too long to fix anything and the usual idea is that they close tickets right away due to inactivity (even though the issue persists). Drives me nuts.

Anyhow, my sledge hammer work around/hack is the following: Apply a TextColor deemd good enough (try a few that might work for you), onApprearing:

Ex:

```
private void SetAllEntryTextColorsForIOS()
{
   #if IOS
   MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
   {
     var controls = this.GetVisualTreeDescendants();

     foreach (var child in controls)
     {
         if (child is Entry)
         {                 
             (child as Entry).Style = null;
             (child as Entry).BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
             (child as Entry).TextColor = Color.FromArgb("#1E1E1E");  
         }
     }
   });
   #endif
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();   
   SetAllEntryTextColorsForIOS();
}
```